# Why the_title() is returning me the title of the post before I call the loop?

Tags: wordpress, themes

A complete noob here with wordpress, I'm learning theme development for wordpress.

Is more for a scientific interest than a problem.

I'm making a single.php page for my theme and I have this and is working.

```
<?php get_header();?>
<h2 class="mb-4"><?php the_title();?></h2>
<div class="row">
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) {

    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post();

        the_content();

    }
}
?>
</div>
<?php
get_footer(); ?>
```

I'm wondering why does this work. Why the_title() is giving me the title of my post before I call the loop. If I do a var_dump(the_post()); before the loop I don't get anything. Same if I call the_content() before the loop I don't get anything. I'm previously printing wp_nav_menu() does that have something to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wordPress is a content management system which is designed and developed in a way where single.php is for getting the data of a post. So the_title does not need inside of the loop. For more details I recommend you to read following doc:

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/